# While looping through a function, Error: Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am a newbie to SQL Server 2008. Any help is highly appreciated. If the stored procedure I have written is time consuming factor, can some one please help me to write in a better way.

```
Table Name: tblProduct
Column Names: Product No, S1_CR, S1_CAT1, S1_CAT2, S1_CAT3, S1_CAT4
Eg Column Values: 1234, Prod1#Prod2#Prod3, 10#200#300, 20#34#400, 40#12#12, 50#23#12
```

I am trying to populate a table which will show up like (when the Input is Prod2),

```
1234  Prod2  200 34 12 23
```

The following error shows up while executing the following stored procedure.

Error: Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

The stored procedure has a function (instr) that is invoked to find the number of occurrences of hash in a string to help in populating the table.

Stored Procedure:

```
Alter Procedure spPopulate
@Code varchar(10),
@Test int,
@Product varchar(10),
@Year varchar(4)
as
Begin 

Declare @Pos int

select @Pos = LEN(SUBSTRING(S1_CR, 0, CHARINDEX(@Code, S1_CR, 0))) - LEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(S1_CR, 0, CHARINDEX(@Code, S1_CR, 0)), '#'  , '')) from tblProduct where Product =@Product and Year = @Year

select ProductNo, s1_cr, s1_cat1, S1_CAT2, S1_CAT3, S1_CAT4,

case
when @Test >= 1 then right(LEFT(s1_CAT1, dbo.INSTR(S1_CAT1+ '#', '#', 1, @Pos+1)-1), (dbo.INSTR(S1_CAT1+ '#', '#', 1, @Pos+1)-1)- (dbo.INSTR(S1_CAT1+ '#', '#', 1, @Pos)+1)+1) end as CAT1,

case 
when @Test >= 2 then right(LEFT(s1_CAT2, dbo.INSTR(S1_CAT2+ '#', '#', 1, @Pos+1)-1), (dbo.INSTR(S1_CAT2+ '#', '#', 1, @Pos+1)-1)- (dbo.INSTR(S1_CAT2+ '#', '#', 1, @Pos)+1)+1) end as CAT2,

case 
when @Test >= 3 then right(LEFT(s1_CAT3, dbo.INSTR(S1_CAT3+ '#', '#', 1, @Pos+1)-1), (dbo.INSTR(S1_CAT3+ '#', '#', 1, @Pos+1)-1)- (dbo.INSTR(S1_CAT3+ '#', '#', 1, @Pos)+1)+1) end AS CAT3,

case 
when @Test >= 4 then right(LEFT(s1_CAT4, dbo.INSTR(S1_CAT4+ '#', '#', 1, @Pos+1)-1), (dbo.INSTR(S1_CAT4+ '#', '#', 1, @Pos+1)-1)- (dbo.INSTR(S1_CAT4+ '#', '#', 1, @Pos)+1)+1) end AS CAT4

from Product where Product=@Product and Year = @Year ;

End

Execute spPopulate @Code = 'Prod1', @Product= 'ProductName1', @Year = '2010', @Test = 1
```

Please find below the function for instr

```
  ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[INSTR] (@str VARCHAR(8000), @substr VARCHAR(255), @start INT, @occurrence INT)
  RETURNS INT
  AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @found INT = @occurrence,
            @pos INT = @start;

    WHILE 1=1 
    BEGIN
        -- Find the next occurrence
        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@substr, @str, @pos);

        -- Nothing found
        IF @pos IS NULL OR @pos = 0
            RETURN @pos;

        -- The required occurrence found
        IF @found = 1
            BREAK;

        -- Prepare to find another one occurrence
        SET @found = @found - 1;
        SET @pos = @pos + 1;
    END

    RETURN @pos;
  END
```

Comment: string handling is often very slow....Especially if you have written an InStr() method , and if applying to all or many rows...You can often replace with LIKE

Comment: It looks like the right solution is a better data structure. Using hashes to separate values then attempting to split them out using queries goes against the purpose of a relational database. You will resolve both the recursion error and the speed issue with a better data structure.

Comment: 100% agree with @ Lathejockey81: Normalise.

Comment: @Lathejockey81 sir/mam, can you please suggest me how can I provide a better data structure for this table. Thanks in advance for your time. If you could msg me some sites where I can find some good database designs also will be really really helpful to newbies likes me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im going to assume that the purpose of this exercise is to split the values out of the columns so that you can then normalise your data.

1. regarding the actual error read @Amir's answer
2. regarding helping you with solving your problem have a look at my approach below, hopefully you can pull something from that to help you.

```
-- set up our sample datasource
declare @source as table 
(
    ProductNo int, 
    S1_CR varchar(100), 
    S1_CAT1 varchar(100), 
    S1_CAT2 varchar(100), 
    S1_CAT3 varchar(100), 
    S1_CAT4 varchar(100)
)

insert into @source values (1234, 'Prod1#Prod2#Prod3', '10#200#300', '20#34#400', '40#12#12', '50#23#12')

-- set up what will become input parameters to our sp
declare @prodNo     int = 1234
declare @code       varchar(10) = 'Prod2'
--Note that there are not Columns named Product, Year in the sample data but you refer to it in your Query so I assume they exist
declare @Product    varchar(10) -- is your declaration long enough? calling your sp you use 'ProductName1' which wont fit.
declare @year       varchar(4) = '2010'

-- this could be a constant if it doesnt change from record to record,
-- or a parameter if it does
declare @delimiter  char    = '#'

--declare our variables
declare @output     table
(
    ProductNo int, 
    S1_CR   varchar(100), 
    S1_CAT1 varchar(100), 
    S1_CAT2 varchar(100), 
    S1_CAT3 varchar(100), 
    S1_CAT4 varchar(100)
)

declare @ProductNo  int 
declare @S1_CR      varchar(100)
declare @S1_CAT1    varchar(100) 
declare @S1_CAT2    varchar(100) 
declare @S1_CAT3    varchar(100) 
declare @S1_CAT4    varchar(100)

--these ones are used during validation
declare @index      int = 1     
declare @term_count int = 0 -- this counts the number of terms in the column we are looking at
declare @num_terms  int = 0 -- this becomes our fixed comparison value
declare @reviewing  varchar(100) -- this is the data from the column we are looking at

select 
    @ProductNo = s.ProductNo,
    @S1_CR = s.S1_CR + @delimiter,
    @S1_CAT1 = s.S1_CAT1 + @delimiter,  
    @S1_CAT2 = s.S1_CAT2 + @delimiter,
    @S1_CAT3 = s.S1_CAT3 + @delimiter,
    @S1_CAT4 = s.S1_CAT4 + @delimiter
from @source s
where s.ProductNo = @prodNo

set @reviewing = @S1_CR

--validate to ensure there are equal number of concatenated terms in each column
--you will probably want to do other validation on inputs etc.
while @index > 0 --and @num_terms > 0
begin

    set @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @reviewing, @index +1)

    if @index > 0 
        set @term_count = @term_count + 1
    else if @index = 0 and @term_count  @num_terms and @reviewing  @S1_CR -- num_terms will be zero when reviewing the first column
        set @num_terms = 0
    else 
        begin

            select 
                @num_terms = case @reviewing
                                when @S1_CR then @term_count
                                else @num_terms
                            end,
                @reviewing = case @reviewing
                                when @S1_CR then @S1_CAT1
                                when @S1_CAT1 then @S1_CAT2
                                when @S1_CAT2 then @S1_CAT3
                                when @S1_CAT3 then @S1_CAT4 
                                else ''
                            end

            if @reviewing = ''
                set @index = 0
            else
                set @index = 1
                set @term_count = 0
        end
end

--Split out the terms
while @num_terms > 0
begin    
    insert into @output values
    (
        @ProductNo,
        left(@S1_CR,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@S1_CR,1) -1),
        left(@S1_CAT1,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@S1_CAT1,1) -1),
        left(@S1_CAT2,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@S1_CAT2,1) -1),
        left(@S1_CAT3,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@S1_CAT3,1) -1),
        left(@S1_CAT4,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@S1_CAT4,1) -1)
    )

    set @S1_CR = right(@S1_CR,len(@S1_CR) - CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@S1_CR,1))
    set @S1_CAT1 = right(@S1_CAT1,len(@S1_CAT1) - CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@S1_CAT1,1))
    set @S1_CAT2 = right(@S1_CAT2,len(@S1_CAT2) - CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@S1_CAT2,1))
    set @S1_CAT3 = right(@S1_CAT3,len(@S1_CAT3) - CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@S1_CAT3,1))
    set @S1_CAT4 = right(@S1_CAT4,len(@S1_CAT4) - CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@S1_CAT4,1))

    set @num_terms = @num_terms - 1
end

select * from @output where S1_CR = @code
```

Comment: Wow.. I must sincerely appreciate your effort and time you have spent. I am having trouble while executing this portion of code, could you help me please,     else if '@'index = 0 and '@'term_count  '@'num_terms and '@'reviewing  '@'S1_CR -- num_terms will be zero when reviewing the first column. This is the error I am gettig - Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 70
Incorrect syntax near ''@'num_terms'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 72
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.   Thanks again.

Comment: @Katheeja - SO removed <> when I pasted sorry... replace with "else if '@index = 0 and '@term_count <> '@num_terms and '@reviewing <> '@S1_CR" you will need to remove leading single quote from variable names

Comment: Wow wow wow.. Thanks infinite.. too good. God Bless you. I will study the code again and again :-) You may not understand the excitement I have from my end. Thank you for your time again.

Comment: How do I modify the code to get all records matching Prod2.   insert into '@source values (1234, 'Prod1#Prod2#Prod3#Prod4', '1#6#8#2', '2#3#4#9', '3#4#1#2', '2#3#8#9')  
insert into '@source values (1890, 'Prod10#Prod5#Prod9#Prod2', '5#1#9#2', '3#2#1#5', '4#8#9#1', '4#2#1#2')
insert into '@source values (1547, 'Prod6#Prod4#Prod2#Prod9', '3#6#9#8', '9#5#4#1', '1#2#3#4', '5#6#7#8')

Comment: I hope ultimately the intention is to get all the data out of that crazy format. assuming this is all historical data and you are pulling out and putting into a new table then, 1. remove the filter from the result set right at the end of the query, 2.make this into the stored procedure like you intended, 3. execute the procedure once for each prodID, 4.store the rows returned into your new table using ProdID/ProdCode for uniqueness. 5. then you can query all the data in the new table however you like and it will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received has to do with recursive calls.

In your solution you didn't place 'GO' between the 'END' and the test execution of the procedure.
Odds are you compiled the execution of the test into the procedure code itself.